# algorítimo não fazendo as verificações necessárias

Tags: visualg

olá, tenho que fazer um algorítimo no visualg onde tem que ler do teclado um valor inteiro positivo e mostrar na tela todos os números primos menores que o número lido do teclado, porém, está sendo mostrado apenas o valor digitado caso ele seja primo, em baixo segue o que fiz:

Algoritmo "semnome"

```
Var
cont , x, v1, aux: inteiro


Inicio
escreval ("digite um valor")
leia (v1)
aux<-v1
repita
      para x de 1 ate aux faca
           se (v1%x=0) entao
              cont<-cont+1
           fimse
      fimpara
      se (cont=2) entao
         escreval (v1)
      fimse
      v1<-v1-1
ate (v1<0)

Fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não definiu nenhum valor para x então ele tem por padrão o valor 0, olhe na condição "se v1 mod x é igual a 0", está acontecendo uma divisão por zero. Para verificar se é primo, o número deve ser dividido por 1 ou ele mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Como qualquer número sempre é divisível por 1 e por ele mesmo, para o número ser primo basta não ter nenhum outro divisor.

```
Algoritmo "semnome"
Var
    cont, cont2 , x, v1, aux: inteiro
Inicio
    escreval ("digite um valor")
    leia (v1)
    aux<-v1
    repita
        cont2 <- 0
        para x de 2 ate aux-1 faca
            se (v1%x=0) entao
                cont2 <-cont2 + 1
            fimse
        fimpara
        se (cont2=0) entao
            escreval (v1)
        fimse
        v1 <- v1 - 1
    ate (v1<=0)
Fimalgoritmo
```

Para otimizar um pouco mais você pode fazer:

```
        para x de 2 ate aux\2 faca
```